# SQL with table name as parameter and query longer than 4000 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that takes a table name as a parameter. Yes I already know this is a security vulnerability, but this is an internal stored proc that doesn't face typical risks of SQL Injection.

What I have so far is something like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myprocedure]
    @tableName sysname
AS
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(4000)
SET @cmd = N' Select blah blah from ' + @tableName
EXEC (@cmd)
GO
```

The query will work in theory, but my problem is that my query is longer than 4000 characters. Is there another way to use @tableName in a cmd variable longer than 4000 characters (which is nvarchar's max)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use SQL Server >= 2005, try replacing `nvarchar(4000)` with `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: That did not work. I am running SQL Server 2005. The problem is that the MAX is actually 4000.

Comment: @a432511: That's not correct.  The maximum size of varchar(MAX) is 2^31.

Comment: Hm... I am beginning to think you are right with this suggestion and it may have fixed my main issue, but I also have a syntax problem in my query. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

Comment: That did not work. I am running SQL Server 2005. The problem is that the MAX is actually 4000.

Comment: No, MAX is 2^31-1 which is actually 2147483647

Comment: 1+ you were correct along with Heinzi, but he responded first. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Extract some of your logic into views or user defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000)
```

instead of `DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);`

```
NVARCHAR(MAX) ALLOWS ONLY 4000 CHARACTERS.
```